# Application of Box-cox transformation consecutively

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity

as far as I have searched  even we can obtain optimal lambda value to transform data to normal distributed with constant variance in box cox transformation method we may have not proper normal distributed data points. In short at the end we have just closer form of normal distribution. Well what  happens if we apply box cox transformation multiple times?  Make our data much Closer to normal distribution than previous case?

No sufficient information about that on internet or books...

Comment: Perhaps you need to adjust for outliers AND/OR variance change detection as discussed here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html

Comment: Because Box-Cox transformations apply only to non-negative numbers and always result in some negative numbers, this possibility is automatically precluded.  You always could use power transformations or other linear transforms of Box-Cox transformations to produce non-negative numbers and repeat, and occasionally this can work--but the circumstances are extremely rare, require quite a few parameters to fit, and are difficult to interpret.

Comment: Whuber, what if we sum the data  with a positive constant  while we have negative transformed variable?  Thus our transtormed data would  be positive and we would have a chance again to apply box cox transformation and make data much more closer to normal distribution. What do you say?

Comment: I already covered that situation in my previous comment.  You can do whatever you want to re-express your variables--there's no need to stick to the Box-Cox family at all--but it's up to you to keep track of the parameters you have thereby introduced and to interpret the resulting (rather complicated) transformation.  My experience is that iterating Box-Cox transformations never pays off, but it's possible there are situations where it could be a good choice.

Comment: Why iterating box-cox transformation never pays off? What is the mathematical explanation of it whuber?

Comment: Secondly what other methods do you suggest to normalize data? Same question also for reducing the heteroscedasticity?

Comment: Guys; you both praise and denigrate box-cox transformations. In short I really do not  understand it is applicable in multiple times? Could you help me again about that?